# kong ingress controller with user-specified loadbalancerIP

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, kong-ingress

I have an aks cluster and I want to install a kong ingress controller with my pre-existing IP address, but I can't find a way to set this value when installing with helm

in [value.yaml](https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/main/charts/kong/values.yaml) file, I didn't found any loadBalancerIP value that can be set, but in the [_helpers.tpl](https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/main/charts/kong/templates/_helpers.tpl#L120) file, I found some mention for the loadBalancerIP field, but I didn't understand how to pass a value to this file.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just do this:

```
helm template kong/kong --generate-name --set proxy.loadBalancerIP="yourIP"
```

Comment: thank you, that works for me.
how I can find those value options if they are not set in the values.yaml file?

Comment: just look at the helm code, its evident its asking for loadbalancerIP there, after that you just need to figure out where its being passed, which is also quite trivial looking at the proxy-service.yaml or something like that